# Firestore Rules: How to allow specific editing of someone else's record?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an app that has Users, and Jobs.

Each Job is owned by 1 User. Only that User can edit the job.

Any User can apply to any Job. When a User applies to a Job, I want to add that user to the `job.appliedCandidates` array. Basically the structure is this:

```
Jobs
    - Job1
        - owner = User1
        - candidatesApplied
            - User2
            - User3
```

So User1 owns Job1. Let's say User4 comes along and applies to the job. Now I want to add him to `candidatesApplied`. But he doesn't have editing access to that job because he's not the owner!

And if I give him editing access, then he can change *all* the job data. Not what I want.

I'm pretty sure in Firestore you can do rules on a per-field basis, but this still doesn't solve my problem. If User4 can edit `job1.candidatesApplied`, that means he has access to delete the other users from the array!

I'm pretty sure that the array setup I've got going is not the way to go. One idea is to have "applicants" be a subcollection of a job, and allow any user to create a record in that subcollection, but not do anything else. But I'm not sure if this is right either.

How best should I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you haven't set limits on how many applicants can apply for a job, let's just assume that the list of applicants can grow massively.  If that's the case, then even modeling that data as a list in a single document is prone to error since there is a discrete max size to a document: 1 MB.  And we're not even talking about security yet.

In order to avoid the max document size problem, the best way to deal with this is by putting each applicant in their own document.  Whether or not that's a collection or subcollection is mostly irrelevant.

If you choose to store each applicant as a document in a collection, now you are not constrained to some arbitrary maximum of applicants, and it's easier to write rules for that.  What those rules should be are outside of the scope of what you've proposed here so far.  But flexible data modeling suggests that the subcollection approach is less prone to problems.

Comment: Hmm good point. I hadn't considered document size. Even without reaching that 1MB limit, it means that simply loading the job will be slower the more applicants there are.

Thanks for this. I will try the subcollection approach and see how that goes.